# Como puedo capitalizar un string?

Tags: javascript

Quiero pasar esto

var cadena = "hola como estan";

a esto.

var cadenaDos = "Hola Como Estan";

Poner en mayuscula la primer letra de cada palabras.

Comment: Que has intentado? Recuerda leer [ask]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo hacer para que aparezcan las primeras letras de las palabras en mayusculas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111241/como-puedo-hacer-para-que-aparezcan-las-primeras-letras-de-las-palabras-en-mayu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función recibe una cadena de texto por parámetro.

Luego usando la funcion replace de javascript le pasas un texto que quieres cambiar por otro.

Aqui uso una expresion regular:

**\w**: cualquier letra del abecedario (mayuscula o minuscula), numero o _

**\S**: cualquier cosa que no sea un espacio.

Esto muchas veces, por el cuantificador * (0 a muchas)

En la cadena "hola como estan", encontraria 3 coincidencias: "hola", "como", "estan".

Despues cada coincidencia es sustituida por lo que devuelve la funcion anonima.

**Funcion anonima**: devuelve un toUpperCase del primer caracter de la coincidencia concatenado con un toLowerCase del resto de caracteres de la coincidencia.

```js
function capitalizar(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}


let cadena = "hola como estan";

console.log(capitalizar(cadena));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const capitalizada = (texto) =>{

   let palabras = [];

   for(let palabra of texto.split(" ")){
    palabras.push(palabra[0].toUpperCase() + palabra.substring(1))
   }
   
   return palabras.join(" ")
}


console.log(capitalizada("fabian es lindo pero papasote"));
```