# como convertir la primer letra de un texto en español en mayuscula con svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

con el siguiente código, si lo hace pero al poner un acento la siguiente letra la pone en mayúscula
`

```
let str = "hola mundo caótico";

str = str.replace(/\b\w/g, function(letter) {
  return letter.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(str); // "Hola Mundo CaóTico"
```

`

Comment: Normalmente del formato se encarga css, no javascript. Lo que pretendes hacer es muy muy fácil con css, hay algún motivo por el que no puedas usar css? A no ser que quieras usar solo la consola por algún motivo

Comment: ¿Porqué usar una expresión regular para eso?

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar esto, puse una expresión regular fuera de la función `replace()` y luego usarlo.

Ésta expresión está en [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/396315/155688) original.

```js
let str = "Hola mundo caótico"; 
const exprecion = /(^|[^A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñ])(?:([a-záéíóúüñ])|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]))|([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]+)/gu;

str = str.replace(exprecion, function(letter) { 
     return letter.toUpperCase(); 
});

console.log(str) // Hola Mundo Caótico
```

Comment: Si ya hay una respuesta a la pregunta, lo propio es marcar esta pregunta como **duplicada** y no responderla. Tienes suficiente reputación en el sitio para conocer las normas y reglas del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función que reciba el string y dentro verifica cuantos espaciado existe en el texto y si existe mas de uno cortamos el texto con el metodo split(' ') pasando como parametro un espacio creamos una constante de tipo arreglo para almacenar los nuevos valores, con el metodo forEach recorremos el split que hicimos del string;

para cada cadena de texto utilizamos el metodo slice con los siguientes parametros ejp: slice(0,1) = al primer caracter del string, y slice(1) = al resto de la cadena.

cargamos al bufer y retornamos el bufer aplicando el metodo join con un espaciado como parametro ejp: bufer.join(' ').

de esta forma estaremos regresando la cadena unificada

```
    let str = "hola mundo caótico";
    function firUpperCase(string) {
        if(string.split(' ').length>1){
            let str = string.split(' ')
            const bufer = []
            str.forEach(st=>{
                bufer.push(st.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + st.slice(1).toLowerCase())
            })
            return bufer.join(' ')
        }
        return string.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    }
    console.log(firUpperCase(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Te puede servir esta función.

```javascript
const capitalizarPalabras = (text) => {
    const words = text.split(' ');
    const capitalizedWords = words.map((word) => {
        const firstLetter = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        const restOfWord = word.slice(1);
        return `${firstLetter}${restOfWord}`;
    });

    return capitalizedWords.join(' ');
};

const str = 'Hola mundo caótico';

const mayus = capitalizarPalabras(str);

console.log(mayus); //Hola Mundo Caótico
```

Lo que mencionan de css lo puedes hacer de la sigueinte manera:

```
<span>hola mundo caótico</span>
<style>
  span{ 
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
</style>
```

te dará el texto del espan: "Hola Mundo Caótico"